# Vaadin8 grid nested property error

Tags: java, spring-boot, vaadin8, nested-properties

I'm trying to create a grid with a nested property. But I can not find a way to show nested property field in grid column.

```
    private Component buildGrid() {

        branchGrid = new Grid<>(Branch.class);
        branchGrid.setItems(DummyData.allBranches);
        branchGrid.setSelectionMode(Grid.SelectionMode.SINGLE);
        branchGrid.setSizeFull();
        branchGrid.getEditor().setEnabled(false);

        branchGrid.addComponentColumn((ValueProvider<Branch, Component>) branch -> {
            Button btnEdit = new Button(VaadinIcons.EDIT);
            btnEdit.addStyleName(MaterialTheme.BUTTON_CUSTOM + " " + MaterialTheme.BUTTON_BORDER);
            btnEdit.setDescription("Click for edit!");
            return btnEdit;
        }).setId("edit");

        branchGrid.setColumnOrder("edit", "branchId", "branchName", "email", "phone", "location", "owner", "active");

        return branchGrid;
    }


public class Branch {

    private String branchId; //yymmddHHmmSSS
    private String branchName;
    private String email;
    private String phone;
    private String location;
    private User owner;
    private boolean active;
}

public class User {

    private long userId;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String email; 
}
```

I want to just show user.username in grid. But in this code, show all user object stack reference or else.

like this: **com.meyrasoft.checkupbox.model.User@12703bc**

Comment: Had you attempt to define in Branch String getOwner() { return owner.username; } ? Or redefine toString on User class? Vaadin is using toString method of User class to show its representantion as String, and as it is not defined, it uses the default one. NOTE: all your properties are private and with no access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a simple way for this solution. If we define **Grid <\Branch/> branchGrid**, we should to use addColumn() definition like below.

```
private Component buildGrid() {

        Grid<Branch> branchGrid = new Grid<>();
        branchGrid.setItems(DummyData.allBranches);
        branchGrid.setSelectionMode(Grid.SelectionMode.SINGLE);
        branchGrid.setSizeFull();
        branchGrid.getEditor().setEnabled(false);

        branchGrid.addComponentColumn((ValueProvider<Branch, Component>) branch -> {
            Button btnEdit = new Button(VaadinIcons.EDIT);
            btnEdit.addStyleName(MaterialTheme.BUTTON_CUSTOM + " " + MaterialTheme.BUTTON_BORDER);
            btnEdit.setDescription("Click for edit!");
            return btnEdit;
        }).setId("edit");

        branchGrid.addColumn(b -> b.getBranchId()).setCaption("Branch Id");
        branchGrid.addColumn(b -> b.getBranchName()).setCaption("Branch Name");
        branchGrid.addColumn(b -> b.getEmail()).setCaption("E-Mail");
        branchGrid.addColumn(b -> b.getPhone()).setCaption("Phone");
        branchGrid.addColumn(b -> b.getLocation()).setCaption("Location");
        branchGrid.addColumn(b -> String.valueOf(b.getOwner().getUsername())).setCaption("Owner");
        branchGrid.addColumn(b -> b.isActive()).setCaption("Active Status");

        return branchGrid;
    }
```